# Telerik: Click on "canceledit" opens deleteConfirm-Dialog

Tags: asp.net-core, telerik

I included the TreeList-Component in my view like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeList<TaxonomyTreeNodeViewModel>()
          .Name("treelist")
          .Toolbar(
              toolbar =>
              {
                  /*toolbar init*/
              }
          )
          .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Add().Field(e => e.GermanTranslation);
              columns.Add().Field(e => e.Sequence);
              columns.Add().Command(c =>
              {
                  if (!Model.IsPublished)
                      c.Edit();
                  if (!Model.IsPublished)
                      c.Destroy();
                  if (!Model.IsPublished)
                      c.CreateChild();
              });
          })
          .Editable(editable => editable.Move(true))
          .Reorderable(true)
          .Filterable()
          .Sortable()
          .Editable()
          .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
              .Read(read => read.Action("All", "DashboardTaxonomy"))
              .Update(update => update.Action("Update", "DashboardTaxonomy"))
              .Create(create => create.Action("Create", "DashboardTaxonomy"))
              .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Destroy", "DashboardTaxonomy"))
              .ServerOperation(false)
              .Model(m =>
              {
                  m.Id(f => f.Id);
                  m.ParentId(f => f.ParentId);
                  m.Field(f => f.EnglishTranslation);
                  m.Field(f => f.Sequence);

              })
          )
          .Events(
              events =>
                  {
                      events.DataBound("TaxonomyTreeWidget.dataBound");
                  }
          )
          )
}
```

My Model:

```
public class TaxonomyTreeNodeViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ParentId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Reihenfolge")]
    public int Sequence { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Deutsche Bezeichnung")]
    public string GermanTranslation { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Englische Bezeichnung")]
    public string EnglishTranslation { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Versionsnummer")]
    public int Version { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Veröffentlicht")]
    public bool Published { get; set; }
   /*[...]*/
```

}

The TreeListrenders the expected result. When I click on an edit-button I'm able to edit and save the data-row.

But when I cancel the Edit a Confirm Dialog appears (Test: "Are you sure you want to delete this record?") and the button with data-command="canceledit" is deleted from the DOM and a data-command="destroy"-Button appears.

Please help,

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue with a small work around. The following TypeScript overrides the cancel method of the `kendoTreelist`:

```
$(() => {
    $('body').on('click', '#treelist', () => {
        $('#treelist').data('kendoTreeList').bind('cancel', e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#treelist').data('kendoTreeList').dataSource.read();
        });
    });
});
```

So if a user triggers the cancel Button, the treelist is set to it's inital state.